# Проиграть несколько видео файлов по очереди в MediaPlayer

Tags: android-studio

Нужно проиграть несколько видео файлов по очереди.

при запуске приложения, проигрывается первый видео-файл, все замечательно.

Как проиграть следующий по завершению текущего или по нажатию на кнопку?

у меня вылетает ошибка, не смотря на то, что файл в папке есть :

Couldn't open /storage/emulated/0/Download/cloud2.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Download/cloud2.mp4

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    private static final String TAG = "videotestmediaplayer";

    private static final String FILE_NAME = "cat.mp4"; // ваш файл

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private TextureView mTextureView;

    public String folderPath,folderPath2;
    public File f;
    public Uri uri;
    public Context context;
    public Button btn;
    public Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //check for permission
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            //ask for permission
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);

        }

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

        folderPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        folderPath2 = folderPath;
        folderPath = folderPath + "/cloud0.mp4";
        folderPath2 = folderPath2 + "/cloud2.mp4";

        f = new File(folderPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "not found");}

        //uri = Uri.parse(folderPath);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                }

                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, folderPath2);
                    uri = Uri.parse(folderPath2);
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        Surface surface = new Surface(mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture());

        try {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            uri = Uri.parse(folderPath);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this ,uri);
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            context = this;
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            Log.d(TAG, this.toString());

            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "finished");
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
                    try {
                        uri = Uri.parse(folderPath2);
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context ,uri);
                        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: ошибка вылетает тут:  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context ,uri);

Answer (score 1):

разобрался сам:
Перед повторным вызовом `setDataSource()` нужно сбросить настройки для повторной инициализации:

```
mMediaPlayer.Reset();                    // <===
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this ,uri);
```